# How to re-ask for user input if user inputted a non-integer

Tags: c, validation, input

How do I keep re-asking the user to enter a valid input that is an integer? I know how to validate an integer range input, but I don't know how to validate a non-integer input when prompted to enter an integer in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int menu;
    while(true) {
        printf("Choose a menu (1-4):\n");
        do {
            scanf("%d", &menu);
        } while(menu < 1 || menu > 4);
        if(menu == 1) {
            printf("menu 1\n");
        } else if(menu == 2) {
            printf("menu 2\n");
        } else if(menu == 3) {
            printf("menu 3\n");
        } else if(menu == 4) {
            printf("menu 4, exit\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sorry if this is a duplicate as everytime I try to search the solution, it's on another language or the thread is asking "how to validate integer input range" instead of non-integer input.

Comment: You need to test the return value from `scanf()`.  If it is EOF, there won't be any more input.  If it is zero, then what's waiting in the input can't be interpreted as a number.  You need to read past the next character, possibly up until the next newline (`int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know when the user has given a non-integer input, a way of doing that is as follows:

```
char number; /* assuming you'll only need numbers 0-9 */
int menu;

while (true)
{
  scanf("%c",&number);
  if (number >= '0' && number <= '9')
     break;
  else
     printf("The input is not an integer\n");
 }

menu = number - '0' ;
/* write rest of the code here */
```

---

If the input is 1 - 999, you can use this:

```
char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);

while (true)
{
  scanf("%s", s);
  is_int = true;
  menu = 0;
  if (s[3] != '\0')
  {
    printf("integer bigger than 999 not allowed, input again\n");
    continue;
  }
  for (int itr = 0; s[itr] != '\0'; itr++)
    if (s[itr] >= '0' && s[itr] <= '9')
    {
      menu = menu*10 + s[itr]-'0';
    }
    else
    {
      is_int = false;
      printf("not a valid integer, input again\n");
      break;
    }

  if (is_int && menu != 0)
  break;
}
```

Comment: This works, but do you happen to know how to do that if my input range is (1-999)?

Comment: @baronoke I have added some extra code, you can check

Comment: Is it possible to input an integer range such as 1-100 with your second algorithm? I tried, but it seems impossible due to array size and how ASCII works

Comment: @baronoke yes, I tried this code on an online gdb compiler for one digit, two digit and three digit numbers, it worked fine. Are you getting any error? can you share it?

Comment: I meant, is it possible to turn this algorithm into a 1-100 integer range, instead of 0-999

Comment: it will accept number bigger than 100. Put one more condition in the check that breaks the while loop: if (is_int && menu >= range_min && menu <= range_max) break; else printf("Number out of range");. This will solve the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211387/discussion-between-breakpoint-and-baronoke).

Comment: Oh nevermind, It works now, apparently I changed the s[itr] >= '0' to '1', and thats why it wasn't working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Separate input from parsing.

Consider a helper function. Use `fgets()` to read, then parse.

```
// return 0 on success, EOF on end of file
int read_int(const char *prompt, int min, int max, &val) {
  #define LINE_N 100
  while (1) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    char buf[LINE_N];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
      return EOF;
    }

    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    long val = strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);
    // Validate an integer was read and if it is in range
    if (endptr > buf && errno==0 && val >= min && val <= max) {
      return (int) val;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
int menu;
if (get_int("Choose a menu (1-4):\n", 1, 4, &menu) == EOF) {
  printf("Input closed\n");
  return 0;
}

if(menu == 1) {
...
```